# java HttpsServer Unable to create new native thread

Tags: java, https

I'm trying to get my java com.sun.net.HttpsServer to handle requests simultaneously. This is my code so far:

```
InetSocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress(443);
httpsServer = HttpsServer.create(address, 0);
...
ThreadPoolExecutor threadPoolExecutor = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
httpsServer.setExecutor(threadPoolExecutor);
httpsServer.start();
```

This works fine for 1-5 hours but then a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread` gets thrown.

What I have also tried is to use `ThreadPoolExecutor threadPoolExecutor = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(19);` but the exception gets also thrown here after about 20 minutes.

My server specs:
1 core, 1GB RAM, Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

command used to start the server: `java -jar myserver.jar -Xmx600M`

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: This is a known problem, although I could not get the reference to it right now. Basically, the operating system threads lives longer than the associated Java threads, so that you run out of OS threads after some time. I also could not remember how to fix it, sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently switched to Tomcat Embedded and everything works seamless there.